# Can a line be centered around specific text using only css?

Tags: php, html, css

I want to have php generated navigation bar. It will consist of a left side with a list of links to the directories below the current one, a link to the index of the current directory, and the right side with a list of links to directories directly inside the current one.

> tester1 > tester2 | index | tester4a tester4b

I would like to center this navigation bar around 'index', regardless of the length of the left or right. I know I could pad the arrays to equal length within the php that generates it, but I'm interested in whether or not I could do this with html and/or css.

Comment: Can you please make an image to show what you mean by "center this navigation bar on middle"?  Do you want them above/below with everything centered?  Or maybe all in one line, all centered?  Thanks

Comment: what html code are you generating with that? it has no sense to talk about css if there's no html

Comment: @Deryck I have updated the description to perhaps be more clear. I mean centere all on one line.

Comment: @arieljuod The whole thing is within a <div>, and I'm generating a series of links on either side. Specifically, the left is links to the directories above the current one and the right is directories directly below the current one. The center is the index of the current directory.

Comment: so, your html looks <div>something | index | something_else</div>? there's no way you can apply css to that, you need to create some markup for the div's content too, like... <div><span class='left'>something</span><span class='center>index</span><span class='right'>something_else</span></div> so you can style each part, something similar to @relic180 answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty easily actually. You may need to play with the widths to fit your context, but pretty straight forward.

```
<div class="main">
  <div class="left">
    stuff in here
  </div>
  <div class="center>
    INDEX
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    stuff in here too
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.main {
  width: 410px;
  text-align: center;
}

.main > div {
  display: inline-block;
}

.left {
  width: 175px;
  text-align: right;
}

.center {
  width: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}

.right {
  width: 175px;
  text-align: left;
}

.main > div > * {
  display: inline;
}
```

[Fiddle HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/JgMa4/)

Comment: With a minor tweak, this works excellently! The change is that I need to set the width of each section in the html tags (<div class="right" style="width:XXpx;">) because I need to calculate this on a per page basis.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can try  [faking "float:center"](http://css-tricks.com/float-center/)